# google maps js api and Places API Web Service

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

We have a site that uses google places autocomplete feature from google maps javascript api.

I connect api that way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?region=AU&language=en-AU&hl=en&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyDcv7qx<..>"></script>
```

At https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard I enabled Google Places API Web Service and Google Maps JavaScript API. It works but uses 1000 quota for places api and not maps js api 25000.
If I disable Places API Web Service then autocomplete stops working.

Is there a way to make autocomplete work with google maps api and without Places API Web Service (that is supposed for server side)?

and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

Not anymore, see this blog post:  [Building for Scale: Updates to Google Maps APIs Standard Plan](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html)

#4. We now count Google Maps JavaScript API client-side requests towards the daily limit of the associated web service API.*

- [Exceptions may apply](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/standard-plan-2016-update) for implementations that were exceeding new quotas prior to June 22, 2016.